# Is it possible to use powered USB hub as power source and Hub on raspberry PI

Tags: power-supply

I would like to use one hub to power Raspberry Pi and use it as a hub.  So attached is the diagram:
[image]

Is it OK that raspberry Pi gets power from the hub and it is the hub?  I would like to be able to plug hard drives into the other hub connectors?

Answer (score 2):

It may work but is not recommended. The USB 3.0 specifies 0.9 Amp per port. This may result in undervolting or power issues, as the minimum recommended power supply for any Pi is 1 Amp.

Comment: This question does not pertain to available current, but to circular flow of current, from hub to Raspberry Pi via power wire and from Raspberry Pi to Hub via signal wire.  I am hoping that there is no VCC connection between Hub and Raspberry Pi through signal wire.

Comment: The power port of the Pi only connects the power pins, not the data lines. So there is no problem with the logic, but there definitely is a power connection between the Pi and hub via the signal line.

Answer (score 0):

Well I've personally done that myself with a RPi B a few years back, and didn't encounter any issues. Also connected a hard drive (which needed one of those cables with 2 USB plugs on one end, for more power), all from the same USB hub. Giant disclaimer though for the usual reasons.

Comment: I agree with @chintogtokh as I am using such cycled powering of my Raspberry Pi using an USB hub for years. Anyway, I recommend using an USB hub with so called _Battery Charging Standard_. Those devices can provide up to 2.5 A for each Port. You can find such products at [Plugable](http://plugable.com/products/) e.g.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it, it did not work for me.  The system continued to come on and drop out.  I wonder if the issue is specific to USB hub, I will post the exact model later.

Comment: Some USB-Hubs require to have a host up and running in order to provide power to the ports. As @MrksKwsnck stated, you need a USB-Hub with Battery Charging Standard.

Comment: Did you find out why it didn't work?